# Why underscoring a letter like $\underline{F} $ for force, $\underline{\nabla} $ for the differential operator, etc, in Classical Mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, notation

In the following article: [Classsical Mechanics](https://www.academia.edu/37598596/Foundations_of_Mathematical_Physics?email_work_card=title), the letter for force $\underline{F} $, the momentum $\underline{p} $ and even nabla $\underline{ \nabla }$ are underscored.  Is this a way of talking about covariant and contravariant?

Comment: On what page is $W$ underscored? And where does $FW$ appear?

Comment: On page 5 for example.

Comment: If either of these is there, I can’t see it.

Comment: I have corrected the error in the title AND in the text about $\underline{W}.  You were right to point those errors.  Very sorry about that.

Comment: Now the title says “ $\underline{\nabla} $ for Work”. This can’t be right. $\underline{\nabla} $ is a vector differential operator. And the body says $\underline{p}$ means work. It doesn’t; it means momentum.

Comment: I hope that it is now correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a notation for vectors, like $\vec{F}$ or $\mathbf{F}$. It's not that common, but I had at least one instructor use it for a class when I was in undergrad. If you look again carefully, you'll notice the work $W$ is not underscored, because it's a scalar.

Comment: I only saw it with some quite old professors (in the 80’s) who were used to using symbols easily reproduced on a standard typewriter (so backspace underscore works, but there is no nice overhead vector symbol).

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, you have made me remember that once in undergrad, I had a teacher that used this notation.  But for myself, in my notes, I was writing with the arrows. I had completely forgotten this.